# SAF - Checking permissions on Uris not in getPersistedUriPermissions() list

Tags: android, permissions, subdirectory, storage-access-framework

My Android app has to check if a SAF folder is granted read/write permissions.

Some uris are stored as strings because they were selected by the user and granted permission by means of this code:

```
static public String takePermanentReadWritePermissions(Activity activity, Intent data)
{
    int takeFlags = data.getFlags()
    &
    (Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
    ContentResolver resolver = activity.getContentResolver();
    resolver.takePersistableUriPermission(data.getData(),takeFlags);
    return data.getData().toString();
}
```

and the check is performed by means of this code:

```
static boolean arePermissionsGranted(Activity activity, String uriString)
{
    ContentResolver resolver = activity.getContentResolver();
    List<UriPermission> list = resolver.getPersistedUriPermissions();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
    {
        if(((Uri.decode(list.get(i).getUri().toString())).equals( uriString)) && list.get(i).isWritePermission()&& list.get(i).isReadPermission())
        {
        return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Some other uris are created with SAF methods, like for example a folder inside a previously authorized folder. The child folder should be authorized.

Nonetheless my app has to check the permissions grant whether it is still valid at any time.

I would like to be able to check one uri with no regard to the list of authorized uris that are in the app "space".

So I would like to check also uris that were not explicitly included.

Comment: I'm "little" late but maybe it can help someone who wants to try: try to get all allowed URIs by `contentResolver.outgoingPersistedUriPermissions`

Answer (score 0):

> > Some other uris are created with SAF methods, like for example a folder inside a >>previously authorized folder. The child folder should be authorized.

No. Not at all. You automatically have acces to all files and subfolders if the user selected a folder/tree. Also to files and subfolders you created later in it.

It is unclear to me why you would check that.

Comment: The reason I want to be able to check the permissions in a general fashion is that in my app there is a certain freedom for the user to select folders, so if a permission is dropped the app has to check and it does not know if that folder was created by itself

Comment: If the uri of the folder is not in getPersistedUriPermissions() then you should walk down its urischeme and see if the parent folder is in getPersistedUriPermissions() and so on.

Comment: I think that when the app is uninstalled all information about permissions on what it created is lost, I am reasoning about all cases now

Comment: Not only about what is created but also on what is obtained. In short all PersistedUriPermissions are gone then.

Comment: Yes, I have to ponder on some design decisions for a while.